# how to build a loop that write previous number's 1.8 times

Tags: loops, for-loop, math

How to write a for loop which has the step of 1.8

for example

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {echo $i;}
```

`$i` should give me an output like : 1, 1.8, 3.24, 5.8 , 10.5

Comment: *How many* such numbers do you wish to print? When do you wish to stop?

Comment: Please investigate what the `$i++` part is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$i++ means that you are incrementing the value of $i variable by 1 unit (the initial value you assigned to 1. Each following iteration it will be increased by 1 until it reaches 11 (including 11)). If I understood correctly the question, you want to have a step of 1.8

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i= $i * 1.8) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Or another alternative would be:

```
$result = 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $result *= 1.8;
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Java** it's simple as:

```
for (double i = 1; i <= 11; i *= 1.8) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I guess you can convert it to the language you use.